# How to create InternalFrame per menuOption and then select between them

Tags: java, swing, jinternalframe

I am building a GUI using internalFrames. I have a menu with different options and I whenever I choose a new option I want it to create that specific frame. However, if that 'option frame' has been created already when I click the option a second time, then I just want that frame to come on top of the other frames (since they are the same size and will lie on top of each other).
This is some of my methods I use:

This method is created when I click a menuOption named: "Home"

```
protected void createFrameHome()
{
    NewFrame frame = new NewFrame();

    desktop.add(frame);
    try {
        frame.setSelected(true);
    } catch (PropertyVetoException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This Method is created when I click a menuOption named "Travel"

```
protected void createFrameTravel()
{
    NewFrame frame = new NewFrame();
    frame.getContentPane().add(table, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    desktop.add(frame);
    try {
        frame.setSelected(true);
    } catch (PropertyVetoException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Frame create:

```
class NewFrame extends JInternalFrame {
    public NewFrame() {
        setSize(700, 500);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Now as you can see I create a new frame every time these methods are being called. I have tried different things to get it to work but none seems to work.. I have for example used a variable so it doesn't create a new frame, but then it doesn't do the `frame.setSelected(true);` part either.
Does anyone know a way around this? Can I somehow select the frame from before maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by using a variable which was set to true if frame was created